# Simple LInked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have the following single linked list,I always get the length as 1,even if i push 3 elements,and always only one node is created.Please help.Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

};

void push(struct node **head,int data)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=data;
    if(*head == NULL)
    {
        *head=temp;

    }
    else
    {
    temp->next=*head;
    *head=temp;

    }
}

int length(struct node *head)
{
    struct node *temp = head;
    int count=0;
    if(temp !=NULL)
    {
        count++;
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return count;
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    struct node *head=NULL;
    push(&head,1);
    push(&head,2);
    push(&head,3);

    a=length(head);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `if` by `while` in the length function

Answer (score 2):

In your `length` function, change this line:

```
if(temp !=NULL)
```

to this:

```
while(temp != NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you noticed the structure of your length method? You are using an if statement where a loop would be appropriate. You are getting the answer of 1 because you are only executing the count ++ statement once.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from `push()` function. If `head` is not null you need to iterate through the list to the last node. And as said before `while` instead `if`

Answer (score 0):

```
# include <stdlib.h>

void push(struct node **head,int data)
{
struct node *temp;

temp = malloc (sizeof *temp);

temp->data = data;
temp->next = *head;
*head = temp;
}
```